# Deploying updates to a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

I'm looking for high-level insight here, as someone coming from the PHP ecosystem. What's the common way to deploy updates to a live Flask application thats running on a single server (no load balancing nodes), served by some WSGI like Gunicorn behind Nginx?

Specifically, when you pull updates from a git repository or rsync files to the server, I'm assuming this leaves a small window where a request can come through to the application while its files are changing.

I've mostly deployed Laravel applications for production, so to prevent this is use `php artisan down` to throw up a maintenance page while files copy, and `php artisan up` to bring the site back up when its all done.

What's the equivalent with Flask, or is there some other way of handling this (Nginx config)?

Thanks

Comment: If you care about uptime, you'll have redundant webservers, which means you'll have a load-balancer balancing between your servers. So if you want to update to a new version, you select a webserver, remove it from the load-balancing pool (by whatever means works best for your load-balancer), and then update while no traffic is flowing to it. Literally anything that doesn't involve draining traffic away will be vulnerable to errors while the application is being updated.

Comment: Its going to be a pretty simple setup with a single VPS instance. I just don't want a request to be processed in the off-chance that it comes through while files are copying. Displaying a maintenance page is good enough, which it seems like Docker will let me do.

Comment: When I update my app file, they are not reloaded until I reload apache. I suppose nginx behaves the same. Just push the files, and when you're done, reload you web server.

Comment: Yeah I noticed similar behavior when I deployed my application. When I pull updates from my repo, the application doesn't update until I restarted my Gunicorn container. JS files and such things that are just served from a public directory did update though (which makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Docker might be my best bet:

1. Have Nginx running on the host, and the application running in container A with Gunicorn. Nginx directs traffic to container A.
2. Before starting the file sync, tear down container A and start up container B, which listens on the same local port. Container B can be a maintenance page or a copy of the application.
3. Start file sync and wait for it to finish. When done, tear down container B, and start container A again.